# How to know typing status in 1:1 conversation in Smack 4.2 in Android?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am building a chat application in Android. I send and receive message, but I don't know how can I know the other user status and typing status of the conversation.

I have been reading to use ChatManagerLister, but it is deprecated in this version.

In Smack 4.2 the class ChatManager does not have methods to listen chat states.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479355/how-to-send-composing-is-typing-chat-states-event-in-multiuser-chat-group/45814536#45814536

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sarthak Mittal, but I do not see the possible solution. The class `MessageEventManager` is in legacy mode in Smack

Comment: I will be updating my answer properly in the mentioned link in a day or two, bit occupied right now! :)

Comment: btw, I have manually added a syncStanzaListener to listen for typing status changes, and also send it manually, I have already posted the relevant Rx code for typingstatuschanges in the above link! :)

Comment: Ok, Thanks in advance!! I will wait it

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38975804/3556483??

Comment: yes quite similar to this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi used chatstates ejabberd protocol for typing status. please read this doc might be helpful you [XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html)

For android side you need to implement following code

```
    Message msg= (Message) stanza;

    // below ChatStateExtension for Compossing message.
            ChatStateExtension state = (ChatStateExtension)msg.getExtension("http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates");//jabber:x:event
            // if state (ChatStateExtension) !=null and is composing then call listener method if not error.
            if(state!=null) {
                Log.d(AppConstants.ELEMENT,"ChatStateExtension : " + state.toXML());
                if (state.getElementName().equals("composing")) {
                    if (msg.getType().equals(Message.Type.error)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (iCallBackForTypingListener != null) {
                        DelayInformation timestamp = (DelayInformation) msg.getExtension("delay", "urn:xmpp:delay");
                        if (timestamp == null)
                            timestamp = (DelayInformation) msg.getExtension("x", "jabber:x:delay");

                        if (timestamp != null && timestamp.getReason().equalsIgnoreCase("Offline Storage")){ //return if delay info is Offline Storage
                            return;
                        }


        //update your typing listener
    iCallBackForTypingListener.onTypingStanza(fromJID, typingSender);
                    }
//  xmpp.updateChatState(fromJID, state.getElementName(), sender);
                    return;
                } else if (state.getElementName().equals("paused")) {
                    return;
                }
```